# Unity Click and Pass WaitForSeconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making simple 2d game. This is opening scene. (Logos images showing).I want to if mouse click down (0) Time passes and other image show. How can i do it ?

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class OpeningCanvasScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(otherImage());
        
    }
    private void Deactivate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    private IEnumerator otherImage()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            Deactivate();
            transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
            // I want to if mouse click down (0) Time passes and other image show
        }
        SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Either make the wait shorter by only waiting 1 frame at a time and using a variable to track the elapsed time. Or add a log of the clicks to FixedUpdate().

Comment: @John Sorry. I am beginner. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think i did it this way

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class OpeningCanvasScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool finished = false;
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(otherImage());
        
    }
    private void Deactivate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            finished = true;
        }
    }
    private IEnumerator otherImage()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            finished = false;
            Deactivate();
            transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(true);
            StartCoroutine(waitSeconds());
            yield return new WaitUntil(()=>finished);

        }
        SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
    }
    private IEnumerator waitSeconds()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        finished = true;
    }
}
```